# What's the best architecture to use in this case? SQS? SNS? Combination of both?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a central c# windows service on an EC2 instance inside AWS. Its job is to create tasks (instructions inside JSON) which are then sent down to individual windows services running on servers outside of AWS (think bricks & mortar retail stores with a server in each store).

These individual servers perform some processing based on the JSON task, and then send a message back to the central windows service inside AWS.  This design is currently using AWS SQS.

I originally designed this using 1 SQS queue for messages to outside servers, and 1 SQS queue for messages coming back. Two queues in total.

This design appears flawed however, as certain messages are for certain servers only, but in order to work out which message is for which server, the messages must be 'read' off the queue and the JSON examined, which then hides them from other servers polling for messages. This could lead to servers never getting to see their messages as they keep getting hidden by other servers.

So what are my alternatives to this design? There are 400 servers outside AWS. I could have 400 SQS queues (one to each server) and then a single queue back to the central service? It just seems like SO many queues.

I thought about using SNS? But then I'd still have 400 SNS topics right? One for each store?

Comment: Not saying this is ideal, but is it OK for the 400 servers to poll e.g. every 10 minutes, or do you need it to be more or less immediate notification? If polling is OK, you could simply place the JSON documents in S3 at s3://bucketname/serverN (or a database of some kind) and have the client poll for new JSON documents periodically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely should *not* be retrieving Amazon SQS messages that will not be processed. This can lead to a situation where messages are **never retrieved** by the desired server.

Your choice is:

- Create **one queue per server**. They check their own queue. OR
- **Create your own API using API Gateway.** The servers call in, identifying themselves. Messages are retrieved from a database (not SQS) and provided back. **Downside:** You have to write it yourself, do error handling, invisibility-type functionality, etc.

The **first option is the simplest** and requires practically no coding changes. There does not appear to be a limit of the number of queues in SQS. The 400 queues can be created programmatically with a few lines of code.

Depending upon how your application operates, you might also want one **general queue** that any server can grab, and possibly even queues for a particular class of server (eg by geography or capability). Each server would check its own queue first, then the queue for its class, then the general queue.

**A word of caution:** Amazon SQS [charges by API call](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/pricing/) (eg attempting to retrieve a message). Use [long polling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html) to reduce the number of requests.

Comment: Hi there John, thanks for your comments. I think I'll go with the one queue per server. It is highly unlikely we will ever have more than say 500 of these queues required, and - as you point out - I could set the central application so that if a message is destined for a server for which no queue yet exists, a queue can be created programmatically containing the server name as a part of the queue name (so that consumers can dynamically work out the queue name based on their own server name, e.g. C# Environment.Machinename.  Thanks John!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this is SQS. Read through http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-attributes.html

Message which can be consumed by ANY store will NOT have any message attribute; while message for a particular store will have an attribute store=store1.

Now, ALL stores will have two listeners one with message attribute; while one listener with no filter.

ping me if u have any queries.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not assist. The `ReadMessages()` function cannot use a message attribute as a filter, so it is not possible to only retrieve messages for, eg, store1.

Comment: Hi there Deepak, as John has suggested I was under the impression that message attributes could not be used as a means of filtering. I did some research in that regard as it appeared at a glance to be a solution to my problem, but every bit of reading I did suggested that it does not solve my problem. Do you have evidence of message attributes being used in this manner?

Comment: Hi Deepak, you mentioned to ping you if you have any queries. While this question has been answered, I am struggling in another area of Amazon Web Services, mainly Lambda functions using .NET.  There seems to be very few samples, examples or tutorials using .NET (which I understand to a degree as the functionality has been around much longer for Node.js as an example). I have another question posted on SO about Lambda. If you think you could assist, I'd appreciate it if you could take a look.

Comment: So, what is the final solution which worked for you ?  I can try to take a look at your other question; but I am a java & aws guy..

Comment: Hi Deepak - in the end, I have allowed the software to create queues as needed. Each store has its own queue. If a store does not have a queue when the software attempts to send, it creates one using the server name as a part of the queue name. This works out well as it means we don't have to manually create queues - ever. Seems to be scaling OK. There is a single queue for messages in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

As John suggested my above answer might not work; 
One solution could be use any JMS solution providers like ActiveMQ which I have used and for sure provides this functionality; in which you can subscribe to queues based on filters.

bitnami provides an AMI for activemq which you can install on a micro EC2 instance. Its very straight forward.